# Removing Post Meta from Category Pages?

Tags: post-meta

This should be an easy one for everyone here. I am trying to remove the post meta function from my category pages only and keep it everywhere else. I currently have a function:

```
/** Customize the post meta function */
add_filter( 'genesis_post_meta', 'post_meta_filter' );
function post_meta_filter($post_meta) {
if (!is_page()) {
$post_meta = '[post_categories]';
return $post_meta;
}}
```

How can I add an if statement in there to make it so if (is_category()) to make $post_meta = '';

Any ideas? Will be waiting your responses guys, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
/** Customize the post meta function */
add_filter( 'genesis_post_meta', 'post_meta_filter' );
function post_meta_filter($post_meta) {
if (!is_page()) {
    if (is_category()) $post_meta = '';
    else $post_meta = '[post_categories]';
return $post_meta;
}}
```

Comment: Amazing, that did it. Guess I need to start learning PHP.